# ReactJS - setState in parent component submits form despite using preventDefault()

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to show alert when validating form. The problem is when error occures during validation I want to show alert defined in parent component - this causes submiting/reloading form and e.preventDefault() is not enough to stop from submiting. I've figured out that setState passed by props causes submission but I don't know how to setState and prevent from submission. What can I do with this case? I suppose that React Router Dom has something in common because this mechanism works without using routes. Here's some code:

**App.js** (parent component)

```js
import React, { Fragment, Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Alert } from "react-bootstrap";
import Login from "./components/pages/Login";
import Home from "./components/pages/Home";
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        alert: "",
    };
    render() {
        const { alert } = this.state;
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Router>
                    {alert && <Alert variant="danger">{alert}</Alert>}
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={() => <Home />} />
                        <Route exact path="/login" component={() => <Login onShowAlert={(alert) => this.setState({ alert: alert })} />} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

**Login.js** (child component)

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
class Login extends Component {
    state = {
        login: "",
        password: "",
    };
    handleCheckValidation = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { onShowAlert } = this.props;
        onShowAlert("Show some error message"); //this causes submitting form
    };
    render() {
        const { login, password } = this.state;
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleCheckValidation} autoComplete="off">
                    <Form.Control type="email" name="login" value={login} onChange={(e) => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })}></Form.Control>
                    <Form.Control type="password" name="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })}></Form.Control>
                    <Button type="submit" variant="primary">Sign in</Button>
                </Form>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
export default Login;
```

Comment: `this causes submitting form` but it (`onShowAlert`) is in a submit handler already. So the submit handler works as expected. The problem I think here is that your form along with the router gets rerendered because the state in the `App` changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

For the given handler:

```
handleCheckValidation = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { onShowAlert } = this.props;
  onShowAlert("Show some error message");
};
```

I don't see a way for this to submit the form.

I think the issue is with how you render the `Login` component in the `Route`.

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/login"
  component={() => (
    <Login onShowAlert={(alert) => this.setState({ alert: alert })} />
  )}
/>
```

[Route `component`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component)

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the
> router uses `React.createElement` to create a new React element from the
> given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the
> component prop, you would create a new component every render. This
> results in the existing component unmounting and the new component
> mounting instead of just updating the existing component. When using
> an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or the
> children prop.

`this.state.alert` state is updated and `App` is rerendered.

## Solution

Render the component on the `Route`'s `render` prop:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/login"
  render={() => (
    <Login onShowAlert={(alert) => this.setState({ alert: alert })} />
  )}
/>
```

Or as a child component:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/login"
>
  <Login onShowAlert={(alert) => this.setState({ alert: alert })} />
</Route>
```

You'll want to go ahead and fix your home route as well. This can still use the `component` prop since you are *not* injecting additional props.

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

Comment: Not OP, but thanks for the great explanation. Is there ever a time where using component is better instead of render or children?

Comment: @Hyetigran Yes, basically when you don't need to pass any additional props (*see the last edit in my answer about the home route*).

Comment: Yes, changing "component" prop to "render" fixed the problem. Thank you for solution and for explanation! I'll do it the same with Home component :)